# Arduino IDE error: cannot declare variable <object> to be of abstract type <class>

Tags: c++, arduino, accelerometer, sensors, robotics

I can't figure out this error.  I initially copied from CurieIMU.h (which builds ok) to ashIMU.h...

Error is this:
ashIMU.h:17: error: cannot declare variable 'ashIMU' to be of abstract type 'ashIMUClass'

My sketch ARDUINO_LED_DEMO.ino .................

```
#include "ashIMU.h"
...
```

ashIMU.h..................

```
        #ifndef ASH_IMU_API_H
        #define ASH_IMU_API_H

        #include "ash_BMI160.h"

        class ashIMUClass : public ashBMI160Class {

            public:
                bool begin(void);

                void setAccelerometerRange(int range);
        };

    extern ashIMUClass ashIMU;

#endif // ASH_IMU_API_H
```

ash_BMI160.h .....................................
This is just BMI160.h but with class name changed from "BMI160Class" to "ashBMI160Class".

```
...

class ashBMI160Class {
    public:

...

};
```

Comment: And what is `ashBMI160Class`?

Comment: If nothing fishy is going on, it simply means that your class has a pure virtual method. The class of which you'd like to create an instance needs to implement that method.

Comment: Looking at the original BMI160.h, I can see `virtual int serial_buffer_transfer(uint8_t *buf, unsigned tx_cnt, unsigned rx_cnt) = 0;`

Comment: What compiler? gcc provides typically a message which ends with "because the following virtual functions are pure within ..."

Answer (score 0):

If your `ashBMI160Class` is the same as the original `BMI160Class` from the CurieIMU library, then you are missing the implementation of pure virtual function:

`virtual int serial_buffer_transfer(uint8_t *buf, unsigned tx_cnt, unsigned rx_cnt) = 0;`